# System.ArgumentException thrown when switching tabs after creating new tab

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, caliburn.micro

We have found that after the installation of .Net 4.5.1 via Windows Update, the following bug is introduced.  Our current fix, which will not last long term, is to uninstall the update and keep everyone's machine at .Net 4.0.

We have a WPF screen that is used to run and view reports.  Each report is a "ReportViewModel."  The collection of view models is managed in a "ReportManagerViewModel" that manages the collection of tabs which utilize the Caliburn.Micro.Conductor.

If we open an existing tab, the tab loads perfectly.  We then start a new tab, run a report, which brings focus to the new tab and populates its data.  This tab IS part of the collection of tabs now.  If we attempt to switch back to one of the already open tabs, the following occurs:

The first click (clicking on the pre-existing tab the first time) does nothing.  The second click crashes the application with the following error:

> System.ArgumentException:  An item with the same key has already been added.

The funny thing is that when the active tab is switched, Conductor.ActivateItem() is called.  When the error is thrown, this method isn't even called.

Using Visual Studio 2010, Caliburn.Micro v.1.5.2, Telerik WPF Controls Q3 2013 hot fix 1424.

Edit:  We now know that Telerik is not the cause as we switch from RadTabItem to TabItem and  we are not using the Caliburn.Micro.Conductor.

> EXCEPTION: 
>   An item with the same key has already been added.
>   SOURCE: mscorlib
>   STACK TRACE:
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor(IDictionary`2 dictionary, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InternalSelectedItemsStorage..ctor(InternalSelectedItemsStorage collection, IEqualityComparer`1 equalityComparer)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.ApplyCanSelectMultiple()
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SetSelectedHelper(Object item, FrameworkElement UI, Boolean selected)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.NotifyIsSelectedChanged(FrameworkElement container, Boolean selected, RoutedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelected(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>      at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.TabItem.OnSelected(RoutedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.TabItem.OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetCurrentValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.TabItem.OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.OnPreviewGotKeyboardFocusThunk(Object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>      at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
>      at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>      at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
>      at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>      at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
>      at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.TryChangeFocus(DependencyObject newFocus, IKeyboardInputProvider keyboardInputProvider, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
>      at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(DependencyObject focus, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
>      at System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(IInputElement element)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()
>      at System.Windows.Controls.TabItem.SetFocus()
>      at System.Windows.Controls.TabItem.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>      at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
>      at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>      at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>      at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
>      at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>      at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
>      at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>      at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
>      at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
>      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
>      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>      at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>      at [AppName].Windows.Program.Main() in M:\Projects[AppName]\Windows\Program.cs:line 129

Comment: Have you tried reproducing the problem in a simpler environment? Without using the Telerik Controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2909048

The "GetHashCode()" and "Equals()" methods of the TabViewModel is the source of the issue.  These will need to be re-written or eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

Just an elaboration on the accepted answer. I had this same ArgumentException with a ListBox when I changed the bound value and reselected the item (plus DataTemplate swapping on selection). The following worked for me (of course you have to make sure the Index values are unique across the List):

```
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is ExtendedButton2Content)
            {
                ExtendedButton2Content temp = (ExtendedButton2Content)obj;
                return temp.Index == this.Index;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Index;
        }
```